# Accessing list within a dictionary via Python from a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python and could use some help, please.  I'm trying to use Python to read from my JSON file and get the values of the list within in a dictionary.

Once I read the JSON into my program, I have:

```
request body = {
  "providerName": "ProviderNameXYZ",
  "rateRequestPayments": [
    {
      "amount": 128.0,
      "creditorProfileId": "7539903942457444658",
      "debtorProfileId": "2072612712266192555",
      "paymentMethodId": "2646780961603748694016",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "userReference": "INVALID user ref automation single",
      "reconciliationId": "343546578753349"
    },
    {
      "amount": 129.0,
      "creditorProfileId": "7539903942457444658",
      "debtorProfileId": "2072612712266192555",
      "paymentMethodId": "2646780961603748694016",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "userReference": "INVALID user ref automation single",
      "reconciliationId": "343546578753340"
    }
  ]
}
```

1. I now want to be able to grab the value of any particular key.
   I've tried accessing it via several routes:

- `rateRequestPayments[0].amount`
- `rateRequestPayments()[0].amount`
- `for k, v in request_body.rateRequestPayments():  print(k, v)`
- `for each in request_body.rateRequestPayments:  print(each('amount'))`
- `values = eval(request_body['rateRequestPayments']) print(values[0])`
  All of these end up with errors.
  Per the 2nd comment below:  `request_body['rateRequestPayments'][0]['amount']`
  This works!

2. I also want to be able to delete the whole key-value pair ("amount": 128.0,) from the request_body.   `request_body['rateRequestPayments'][0]['amount']` does not work for this.  Not sure how to reference this.

I know I am missing something simple but I'm just unsure what it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you include your JSON file to the question please?

Comment: Have you tried `request_body['rateRequestPayments'][0]['amount']`

Comment: dict you have is invalid, keys cannot be duplicated.

Comment: request_body['rateRequestPayments'][0]['amount'] worked!  Thank you!!!!

Comment: I am trying to also use the request_body['rateRequestPayments'][0]['amount'] to reference the key.  I want to delete that line "amount": 128.0,' from my request_body.  But this does not work.  It gives me:"KeyError: "['rateRequestPayments'][0]['amount']"".   Not sure how to reference the whole key/value pair instead of the value itself?

Comment: The values in a dictionary cannot be accessed as though the keys were attribute names like `rateRequestPayments[0]`. Assuming you have deserialized the JSON data into a variable named `result` as a dictionary, you would need to use something like `result['rateRequestPayments'][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Python is great for data science, and has many features that make it fit for the job. One of those features is finding data in a data set. `body['rateRequestPayments'][<!WHICH DATA SET YOU WANT TO ACCESS>][<!VALUE YOU WANT TO FIND>]`

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to put an underscore between `requests` and `body` so its `requests_body = {...}`.

To access a key-value pair:

```py
requests_body["rateRequestPayments"] #to access the list of two dicts
requests_body["rateRequestPayments"][0] #to access the individual dicts by index
requests_body["rateRequestPayments"][0]["amount"] #to access the value of a particular key (in this case "amount" is the key)
```

To delete a key value pair, just use the `del` statement:

```py
del requests_body["rateRequestPayments"][0]["amount"]
```

This will delete the key-value pair in the variable `requests_body`, so trying to access this key again will raise a `KeyError` error.

To access *and* delete a key-value pair, use `.pop()`:

```py
value = requests_body["rateRequestPayments"][0].pop("amount")
#value is now 128.0 and the key-value pair is deleted
```